# Unhandled exception at 0x0f65f508 (msvcr100d.dll)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

So I've been working on a project which is simply a command line program.
The problem I'm running into is when I wanted to create a calculator. The code looks like this:

```
int calculator()
{
char oper[1];
double x, y;
x = 1;
y = 1;
printf("Starting calculator...\n\n");
printf("Input an operator you want to execute: ");
gets(oper);

if (strncmp(oper, "+", 1) == 0)
{
    printf("\ncalculator works like this x + y =\n");
    printf("input x value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",x);
    printf("input y value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",y);
    printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf\n",x, y, x+y);

}
else if (strncmp(oper, "-", 1) == 0)
{
    printf("\ncalculator works like this x - y =\n");
    printf("input x value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",x);
    printf("input y value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",y);
    printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf\n",x, y, x+y);


}
else if (strncmp(oper, "*", 1) == 0)
{
    printf("\ncalculator works like this x * y =\n");
    printf("input x value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",x);
    printf("input y value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",y);
    printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf\n",x, y, x+y);

}
else if (strncmp(oper, "/", 1) == 0)
{
    printf("\ncalculator works like this x / y =\n");
    printf("input x value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",x);
    printf("input y value:\n");
    scanf("%lf",y);
    printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf\n",x, y, x+y);
}
else
{
    printf("Incorrect operator, please try again!\n");
}
}
```

According to few examples and tutorials it should work fine, and it does.
But the problems start after running the code. It works fine until the x value is inserted. Right after it the error shows up:

Unhandled exception at 0x0f74f508 (msvcr100d.dll) in program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

I've seen similar questions like this one but none of them was really giving the fix. Thank you for your help!

Comment: **Never** ever use `gets`! It's broken function that is removed from later C standards. You have at least one buffer overflow because of that! Use `fgets` instead.

Comment: And allocate at least 2 characters for the variable `oper[]` to store the NZ after the operator entered.

Comment: @Lord Wolfram: scanf("%lf",x); hmm... could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Using fgets() didn't solve it. Yes the scanf seem to be the problem. as I tried to execute the code but still after entering x value it crashes.

Comment: @LordWolfram Try this: `char oper[1];` -> `char oper[100];` and report if it works.

Comment: It doesn't. the character input works fine, but after it, the x input is causing error

Comment: ... and did you change all `scanf("%lf", foo);` to `scanf("%lf", &foox);` ? And didn't your compiler show warnings ?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the error! Funny but it didn't. I think that vs2010 doesn't highlight the syntax of c.

Comment: @LordWolfram hard to believe that the compiler didn't warn you, did you have a look in the Error List ? You should get at least `Warning C4477 'scanf' : format string '%lf' requires an argument of type 'double *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double'`. That's what I get with my Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Err.... well I'm using VS 2010 because I'm used to it more.
Therefore it didn't show that. I think, or maybe I didn't notice. I'm also new to C language. My teacher told me to use it so learning it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `scanf("%lf",x);` with `scanf("%lf",&x);`